# ALPS Touchpad speed adjustment with synaptics driver

Tags: drivers, xorg, touchpad, synaptics, alps

How could I change cursor speed (tocuhpad sensitivity?) for AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad from command line?

Answer (score 4):

First check what touchpad device you have and what's its id:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Then copy name of touchpad and see what options does it have and what are the defaults:

```
xinput list-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad"
```

My ALPS touchpad have `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` option with default value of 2.5. To increase cursor speed you need no *decrease* deceleration value (min value is 1). Do it like this:

```
xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1
```

Comment: It's common solution for touchpads supported by synaptics touchpad driver (Synaptics, ALPS, Elantech)